I have issue authorizing my jsonwebtoken how do i go about it?
Hi please i need assistance i tried sending the token i generated using postman it failed and on my terminal is showed jsonwebtoken malformed im lost i need a hand thanks youenter image description hereenter image description here
I have tried checking for where i made mistake but its not clear to me thats why im seeking for assistance

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question.
